# how to check attributes changed value while using callback after_commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using callback "after_commit" and in that i am using rails "changed?" method to know if some attributes value changed.
I read the documentation it seems that "changed? and "_was" methods doesnt work in after_commit callback as values gets reset they work for after_save but i dont want to use that.

```
after_commit :some_function, :on => :update

    def some_function
     if some_attributes_value_changed?  #always returns false
        previous_value = some_attributes_value_was #always shows current value
     end
    end
```

What is the alternate to these methods to know if value changed after database updated.